# Bootstrap 3 checkbox css style in yii2 active form

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, yii2

I have third-party CSS, and I want to use it in a Yii2 `ActiveForm`.

The problem here is: How should I give the classes to a form field?  I tried the following but I am not able to get the desired output.

```
<div class="checkbox checkbox-success">
    <?= $form->field($model, 'is_sold')->checkbox(); ?>
</div>
```

I also tried the following:

```
<div class="checkbox">
    <?= $form->field($model, 'is_sold')->checkbox(['class'=>'checkbox-success']); ?>
</div>
```

But it renders the HTML code like this:

```
<div class="checkbox checkbox-success">
<div class="form-group field-mainads-is_sold has-success">

<input type="hidden" name="MainAds[is_sold]" value="0">
   <label>
     <input type="checkbox" id="mainads-is_sold" name="MainAds[is_sold]" value="1">
     Mark as Sold
   </label>
</div>        
</div>
```

And the desired output I want is something like the following:

```
<div class="checkbox checkbox-success">
    <input class="styled styled" id="checkbox10" type="checkbox">
    <label for="checkbox10">
        This too
    </label>
</div>
```

I have also tried this:

```
 <?= $form->field($model, 'is_sold', ['options' =>  ['class' => 'checkbox checkbox-success']])->checkbox([] ,false) ?>
```

But it didn't work as well, and it gave output like below:

```
<div class="checkbox checkbox-success field-mainads-is_sold has-success">
    <label class="control-label" for="mainads-is_sold">Mark as Sold</label>
    <input type="hidden" name="MainAds[is_sold]" value="0">
    <input type="checkbox" id="mainads-is_sold" name="MainAds[is_sold]" value="1">
</div>
```

The first checkbox in the below image is what I get if I write the HTML code directly, but I want to do it using an `ActiveForm` field. The second checkbox in the image is what I get with form field code.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I found a solution. Try this:

```
<?php $checkboxTemplate = '<div class="checkbox i-checks">{beginLabel}{input}{labelTitle}{endLabel}{error}{hint}</div>'; ?>
<?= $form->field($model, 'rememberMe')->checkbox(['template' => $checkboxTemplate]); ?>
```

And my result:

```
<div class="form-group field-loginform-rememberme">
    <div class="checkbox i-checks">
        <label for="loginform-rememberme">
            <input type="hidden" name="LoginForm[rememberMe]" value="0">     
            <input type="checkbox" id="loginform-rememberme" name="LoginForm[rememberMe]" value="1" checked="">
            Remember Me
        </label>
        <p class="help-block help-block-error"></p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for materialize css design, this template route works.

[image]

```
<?
    $checkboxTemplate = '<label>Terms and Conditions</label><div class="switch">{beginLabel}No{input}{labelTitle}<span class="lever"></span>Yes{endLabel}{error}{hint}</div>';
    echo $form->field($model, 'terms', ['options' =>  ['class' => 'form-group required']])->checkbox(['template' => $checkboxTemplate])->label('');
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try Something like : -

```
 <?= $form->field($model, 'is_sold' ,['options' =>  ['class' => 'checkbox checkbox-success']])->checkbox([] ,false) ?>
```

Comment: i meant about the look and feel of the checkbox. Its not what it should display using the css.